# Unable to shift dates to down!

Tags: tikz-calendar

I was not able to shift the dates to downward position here is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
 \usepackage[left=1cm,bottom=2cm,top=2cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


 %%in preamble:
 %
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning,calendar}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

 \newcommand{\calrow}[1]{\node[anchor=base east,xshift=1em,yshift=-11.5em](Mon){\rotatebox{0}     {\color{blue}Urmi}};
 \node[base right=of Mon,xshift=0.5em](Tue){\rotatebox{0}{\color{blue}Durmi}}; \node[base right=of Tue](Wed){\color{blue}Thelang};
 \node[base right=of Wed](Thu){\color{blue}Theman}; \node[base right=of Thu](Fri){\color{blue}Bhomta};
 \node[base right=of Fri](Sat){\color{blue}Bhomti}; \node[base right=of Sat](Sun){\color{red}Bhomkuru};
 \node[darkgreen,above=of Thu]{\textbf{#1}};
 \node[darkgreen,above=of Sun]{\textbf{\the\year}};}

 \newcommand{\calperiod}[1]{\calendar[dates=\the\year-#1-01 to \the\year-#1-last]
 if(Sunday) [red] \holidays;}

 \newcommand{\holidays}{% holidays in Italy
 if (equals=01-01) [black!50]%
 if (equals=01-06) [black!50]%
 if (equals=04-04) [black!50]%
 if (equals=04-05) [black!50]%
 if (equals=04-25) [black!50]%
 if (equals=05-01) [black!50]%
 if (equals=05-01) [black!50]%
 if (equals=06-02) [black!50]%
 if (equals=08-15) [black!50]%
 if (equals=11-01) [black!50]%
 if (equals=12-08) [black!50]%
 if (equals=12-25) [black!50]%
 if (equals=12-26) [black!50]%
 }
 \pagenumbering{gobble}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \colorlet{darkgreen}{green!0!black}
 \year=2017
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[every calendar/.style={week list},day xshift=4em,yshift=-24cm,darkgreen,node  distance=0.1ex]
 \sffamily
 \node at (12.50,0.90) {\includegraphics[width=15cm,height=5cm]{img/31.jpg}};\\
 \hspace*{60mm}\LARGE{\scalebox{1.0}{\calrow{\color{blue}Arkoi({\it January})} \\
 \calperiod{01}  
 }};

 \end{tikzpicture}


 \end{document}
```

I need dates to print below the row contains Urmi, Durmi...Bhomkuru

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you raise the image instead? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Image is able to raise but this is in the top position so no need to shift the image position, only i need to shift the dates@Troy

Comment: Change the node position to `(12.50,3.90)` and let us know whether it works. It works for the MWE that you posted, at least for me. If there are other constraints, update your MWE with relevant information

Comment: If I shift the image then I will not be able to enlarge the size of the image, so thats the reason i need to shift the dates only@Troy

Comment: I'm utterly confused by your code.. anyway you can pass a coordinate to the calendar to influence its position, which might be what you're looking for. Something like `\calendar at (x,y) [...options...]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `yshift` was at the wrong position. It has to be within `every calendar`.

[image: calendar]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
 \usepackage[left=1cm,bottom=2cm,top=2cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


 %%in preamble:
 %
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning,calendar}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

 \newcommand{\calrow}[1]{\node[anchor=base east,xshift=1em,yshift=-15.5em](Mon){\rotatebox{0}     {\color{blue}Urmi}};
 \node[base right=of Mon,xshift=0.5em](Tue){\rotatebox{0}{\color{blue}Durmi}}; \node[base right=of Tue](Wed){\color{blue}Thelang};
 \node[base right=of Wed](Thu){\color{blue}Theman}; \node[base right=of Thu](Fri){\color{blue}Bhomta};
 \node[base right=of Fri](Sat){\color{blue}Bhomti}; \node[base right=of Sat](Sun){\color{red}Bhomkuru};
 \node[darkgreen,above=of Thu]{\textbf{#1}};
 \node[darkgreen,above=of Sun]{\textbf{\the\year}};}

 \newcommand{\calperiod}[1]{\calendar[dates=\the\year-#1-01 to \the\year-#1-last]
 if(Sunday) [red] \holidays;}

 \newcommand{\holidays}{% holidays in Italy
 if (equals=01-01) [black!50]%
 if (equals=01-06) [black!50]%
 if (equals=04-04) [black!50]%
 if (equals=04-05) [black!50]%
 if (equals=04-25) [black!50]%
 if (equals=05-01) [black!50]%
 if (equals=05-01) [black!50]%
 if (equals=06-02) [black!50]%
 if (equals=08-15) [black!50]%
 if (equals=11-01) [black!50]%
 if (equals=12-08) [black!50]%
 if (equals=12-25) [black!50]%
 if (equals=12-26) [black!50]%
 }
 \pagenumbering{gobble}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \colorlet{darkgreen}{green!0!black}
 \year=2017
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[every calendar/.style={week list,day xshift=4em,yshift=-3cm},darkgreen,node distance=0.1ex,font=\sffamily]
 \node (img) at (12.50,0.90) {\includegraphics[width=15cm,height=5cm]{example-image}};
 \hspace*{60mm}\LARGE{\scalebox{1.0}{\calrow{\color{blue}Arkoi ({\it January})} \\
 \calperiod{01}  
 }};

 \end{tikzpicture}


 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanking you after adjusting according to your suggestion i got the output, but why 1st page become blank page@TeXnician

Comment: @BikiTeron For me there's no blank page.

Comment: Thanking you so much after adjusting the position the blank page is gone @TeXnician